# Unable to replace url

Tags: javascript, html

The code is not able replace URL that is specified

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <button id="device1" onclick="deviceOnOff('device1')">On/Off</button>
    <button id="device2" onclick="deviceOnOff('device2')">On/Off</button>
  </body>
  <script>
    function deviceOnOff(id) {
      window.history.replaceState({}, "", window.location.href + "/" + id);
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

The current URL replaced with: `window.location.href + "/" + id`

Comment: Are there any error messages?

Comment: What **is** happening? Not really sure how this can fail.

Answer (score -1):

Its not clear what you are trying to do: but you can try these:

```
function deviceOnOff(id) {
  window.history.replaceState({}, "", (window.location.href = id));
}
```

OR

```
function deviceOnOff(id) {
  window.history.replaceState({}, "", window.location.replace(id));
}
```

Comment: Both snippets ignore the current URL.

Comment: if you want to retain the current URL you need to remove the "/":  
`(window.location.href = id)`

Comment: That sets the href to the id and still ignores the current href. OP is trying to append to the current href.